# Why has Snow Leopard screwed up my Safari and my desktop's ability to stay organized

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, safari

Ever since I installed snow leopard I get multiple safari crashes per day. And my desktop refuses to stay organized (by date modified)?

Comment: More info? What's the machine? How old? What kind of software is installed? Additional info would be helpful.

Comment: What version of Safari? Be sure to run Software Update from the Apple menu to make sure that everything's updated. My Safari crash issues were fixed in an update.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you did an upgrade, perhaps with the help Migration Assistant?

Best way to deal with it?  Back up your data, and either
i) create a new account, pulling your data back in, but with a fresh library and settings or, better yet,
ii) reformat, re-install OS and create your account again, from scratch.  Pull the data in manually.

Upgrading, and/or migration assistant, often doesn't go well when automated.  Just the nature of the beast. If you're not entirely comfortable doing this, get a pro to do it.  Trust me.

Comment: OK it does go wrong sometimes but I suspect rarely not often

Comment: @Mark.. this is based on my experience as an Apple-certified technician.  :-)  I am an ACTC, I do Mac consulting for a living.  Your experience with migrations may be completely different... my experience has been that if you don't do it manually, problems are almost inevitable.